# CRM : SOAP : Error in ExecuteWorkflowRequest

Tags: javascript, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, dynamics-crm

I want to Execute workflow with SOAP. I've googled all around this and tried different ways. But none of my code works. For example, two most final variants are:
**for 2011 Service**

```
function RunWorkflow() {
    var url = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web";
    var requestMain = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">  <s:Body>";
    requestMain += "    <Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
    requestMain += "      <request i:type=\"b:ExecuteWorkflowRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">";
    requestMain += "        <a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
    requestMain += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "            <c:key>EntityId</c:key>";
    requestMain += "            <c:value i:type=\"d:guid\" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">B8373961-D084-E611-8763-005056810E95</c:value>";
    requestMain += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "            <c:key>WorkflowId</c:key>";
    requestMain += "            <c:value i:type=\"d:guid\" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">191CDD5A-3EBD-40FD-A685-B79D99B32831</c:value>";
    requestMain += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "        </a:Parameters>";
    requestMain += "        <a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
    requestMain += "        <a:RequestName>ExecuteWorkflow</a:RequestName>";
    requestMain += "      </request>";
    requestMain += "    </Execute>";
    requestMain += "  </s:Body>";
    requestMain += "</s:Envelope>";

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () { assignResponse(req); };
    req.send(requestMain);

    function assignResponse(req) {
        if (req.readyState == 4)
            if (req.status == 200)
                alert('successfully executed the workflow');
    }
}
```

**for 2007 Service**

```
function RunWorkflowSeven() {
    var url = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/MSCRMservices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx";

    var soapBody = "<s:Envelope><soap:Body>" +
         "  <Execute xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'>" +
         "    <Request xsi:type=\'ExecuteWorkflowRequest\'>" +
         "      <EntityId>B8373961-D084-E611-8763-005056810E95</EntityId>" +
         "      <WorkflowId>191CDD5A-3EBD-40FD-A685-B79D99B32831</WorkflowId>" +
         "    </Request>" + "  </Execute>" + "</soap:Body>";
    var soapXml = "<soap:Envelope " +
        "  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' " +
        "  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " +
        "  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>" +
        GenerateAuthenticationHeader() + soapBody + "</soap:Envelope>";

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url, false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Execute");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () { assignResponse(req); };
    req.send(soapXml);

    function assignResponse(req) {
        if (req.readyState == 4) 
            if (req.status == 200) 
                alert('successfully executed the workflow');
    }
}
```

The first gives me an error '400: Bad Request',

Other variant of 2011 (request to **'/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/'** instead of **'/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web'** gives '*Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8*'),

The second shows no errors in console but it doesn't run workflow.

Sorry for such a big code but I really don't know where the problem lies.

**UPDATE 1: 
Fiddler shows 3 requests with following status:**

- HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied
- HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication.
- Bad Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in first request you missed one node. Try to replace

```
var requestMain = "  <s:Body>";
```

with

```
var requestMain = "<s:Envelope><s:Body>";
```

Comment: Actually, problem was solved before, when I changed `useAppPoolCredentials` from `False` to `True` in `IIS -> Management->Configuration Editor -> system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication` .
But after all there was a typos in my code that caused this errors.